# R:how to stored and change the input using the function

Tags: r, function

I recently study R, but I am not familiar with using the function. I was trying to use a function to modify my initial input like:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,5,4)
number_to_words<-function(x){
 a<-1
 while(a<8){
     if(x[a]==1){
         as.character(x[a])
         x[a]<-"one"
     }
     else if(x[a]==2){
         as.character(x[a])
         x[a]<-"two"
     }
     else if(x[a]==3){
         as.character(x[a])
         x[a]<-"three"
     }
     else{
         as.character(x[a])
         x[a]<-"four"
     }
     a=a+1    
    
 }
  return(x)
 }
  number_to_words(x)
  x
```

but I found out that the value in x hadn't been changed, whether there is a method that I could let each component of x[a] in my function to be modified and stored?  like x->f(x)->y but x's value is replaced by y?

Comment: The `as(character(x[a])` statements are redundant. The result is not assigned to a variable. You should assign the result of `number_to_words` to a variable. R does not change input arguments. So use `x <- number_to_words(x)`.

Comment: Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have here is that you are assuming that the function is "call by reference" but R uses "call by value". This basically means that a copy of the  arguments you pass into a function is made and it is that copy that you are manipulating inside the function.

The easiest solution in your case is to overwrite `x` when your function returns

```
x <- number_to_words(x)
```